# Raspberry PiとCO2センサーを接続し、プログラムを実行したときに「None」と表示されてしまう。

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

Raspberry Pi 3 を使用して、Co2濃度を計測したいと思っています。

以下のサイトを参考に接続しているのですが、
プログラムを実行した時に「None」と表示され、計測することができません。

原因が分からず、困っています。

どうすれば計測できるのかご教示いただければと思います。

■参考にしているサイト
Raspberry Pi 3 で CO2濃度を測る - Qiita
https://qiita.com/revsystem/items/5a362e749ef80358e801

Comment: その qiita のページ中、"User's Manual" の部分がリンクになっていて、リンク先に mh_z19.py があるのかと思ったのですが、リンク先が存在しませんでした。あなたが実行した mh_z19.py はどこから入手したのでしょうか?

Comment: @masm 恐らくqiitaの記事中で「制御プログラムをgit clone」しているところで取得しています。[該当のリポジトリ](https://github.com/UedaTakeyuki/slider)

Comment: @cubick ありがとうございます。確かにありました。

Comment: @user28473 Raspberry Pi 3 は Model B ですか? `/dev/ttyS0` または `/dev/ttyAMA0` はありますか(どちらがありますか)? 出力されるのは `None` だけですか? 他には何も出力されていませんか? それから関係ないとは思いますが、一応 Python のバージョンはいくつですか? 以上の情報を質問に追記してください。質問のすぐ下に「編集」というリンクがありますので、そこから自由に編集できます。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。一点だけ質問させてください。「/dev/ttyS0 または /dev/ttyAMA0 はありますか」といいますのは、どのような意味でしょうか…？

Comment: @user28473 端末で `ls -l /dev/ttyS0 /dev/ttyAMA0` を実行し、出力結果を質問文に貼り付けてくだされば良いです。

Comment: @masam　ありがとうございます。「ls -l /dev/ttyS0 /dev/ttyAMA0」を実行してみたところ、次の結果が表示されました。

Comment: @masam　ls:'/dev/ttys0/' にアクセスできません：そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 204, 64　5月　10　00：00 /dev/ttyAMA0

Comment: @masam　また、5/9に質問いただいていた件ですが、Noneしか表示されません。他には何も表示されていませんでした。
Pythonのバージョンは、、すみません。わかりません。最近入れたOSです･･。。

Comment: @user28473 Pythonのバージョンは`python -V`と実行すれば確認できるはずです。

Comment: @user28473  `/home/pi/LOG/` というディレクトリの中に、何らかのファイルが作成されていませんか? 発生したエラーがその中に記録されている気がします。あと、私のユーザ名は masam ではなく masm です。そこを間違えると私に通知が来ないため、あなたのメッセージに気づくことができません。

Answer (score 1):

端末で `cat /boot/config.txt | grep enable_uart` を実行して、もし

enable_uart=0

だと、RPi の UART が開いて開いていないのがセンサを読めない原因です
その場合は、ご参考にされた記事
https://qiita.com/revsystem/items/5a362e749ef80358e801　
の元ネタ記事
https://qiita.com/UedaTakeyuki/items/c5226960a7328155635f
の「事前準備(UARTを空ける)」を参考に UART を開かれれば、読めるようになると思います